# Recursive list mnemonics

Tags: java, recursion

I am working on a project to pass in a 3 digit String and it should return an ArrayList of all possible mnemonic combinations. For example, if I pass in the digits "623", it should return a list of 
[MAD MBD MCD NAD NBD NCD OAD OBD OCD
MAE MBE MCE NAE NBE NCE OAE OBE OCE
MAF MBF MCF NAF NBF NCF OAF OBF OCF].

However, I keep getting a result of [MAD, MADE, MADEF, MABD, MABDE, MABDEF, MABCD, MABCDE, MABCDEF, MNAD, MNADE, MNADEF, MNABD, MNABDE, MNABDEF, MNABCD, MNABCDE, MNABCDEF, MNOAD, MNOADE, MNOADEF, MNOABD, MNOABDE, MNOABDEF, MNOABCD, MNOABCDE, MNOABCDEF]. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong here.. It's supposed to return Strings of length 3 and it just appears to tack on the previous letters.

Here is my code:

```
public class PhoneMnemonics {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ArrayList<String> test = listMnemonics("623");
      System.out.print(test);
   }

   public static ArrayList<String> listMnemonics(String number) {
      ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
      recursiveMnemonics(result, "", number);
      return result;
   }

   private static void recursiveMnemonics(ArrayList<String> result, String mnemonicSoFar, String digitsLeft) {
      if (digitsLeft.length() == 0) {
         // Add current mnemonic
         result.add(mnemonicSoFar);
      } else {
         // Try all combinations for single digit
         int numLetters = digitLetters(digitsLeft.charAt(0)).length();
         String letters = digitLetters(digitsLeft.charAt(0));
         if (digitsLeft.length() > 1 ) {
               digitsLeft = digitsLeft.substring(1);
         } else {
               digitsLeft = "";
         }
         for (int i = 0; i < numLetters; i++) {
            char c = letters.charAt(i);
            mnemonicSoFar = mnemonicSoFar + Character.toString(c);
            recursiveMnemonics(result, mnemonicSoFar, digitsLeft);
         }
      }
   }

   public static String digitLetters(char ch) {
      String result = "";
      switch (ch) {
         case '2': result = "ABC";
                  break;
         case '3': result = "DEF";
                  break;
         case '4': result = "GHI";
              break;
         case '5': result = "JKL";
                  break;         
         case '6': result = "MNO";
                  break;         
         case '7': result = "PQRS";
                  break;
         case '8': result = "TUV";
                  break;         
         case '9': result = "WXYZ";
                  break;         
      }
      return result;
   }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: I moved the if statement which edits the digitsLeft string higher in the code and it modified my results a bit.

Comment: Try to download an IDE like eclipse and enter debug mode in it.

Comment: I'm using jGrasp and I've never experimented with the debug feature. After trying just now, nothing pops up. The program itself compiles and runs just fine, but I can't figure out the proper way to recursively call my method.

Comment: The error is in the `for` loop.

Comment: The code is a bit of a mess. To debug search in google a bit. You can set breakpoints where your code will stop and you can check the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that mnemonicSoFar should be fixed after you add it to the results.
For example:

You reach MAD and you add it to the result. After that you need to to the same thing with mnemonicSoFar = MA and the letter to be added E. Notice that you take the the last letter of mnemonicSoFar out.
So you should correct your code to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numLetters; i++) {
                char c = letters.charAt(i);
                mnemonicSoFar = mnemonicSoFar + Character.toString(c);
                recursiveMnemonics2(result, mnemonicSoFar, digitsLeft);
                mnemonicSoFar = mnemonicSoFar.substring(0,mnemonicSoFar.length()-1); 
}
```

If you care to improve your coding style, I refactored your code a bit.

```
private static void recursiveMnemonics(ArrayList<String> result, String mnemonicSoFar, String digitsLeft) {
   if(digitsLeft.length() == 0) {
       result.add(mnemonicSoFar);
       return;
   }
   String letters = digitLetters(digitsLeft.charAt(0));
   digitsLeft = digitsLeft.substring(1);
   for(int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++) {
      mnemonicSoFar = mnemonicSoFar + letters.charAt(i);
      recursiveMnemonics(result, mnemonicSoFar, digitsLeft);
      mnemonicSoFar = mnemonicSoFar.substring(0,mnemonicSoFar.length()-1);
   }
}
```

In my opinion it is much more readable.

Comment: Thank you so much! I know my code got a little out of hand, I was trying my best to work through it and kept forgetting to remove the extra things that I added. I will take your advice and practice the habit of making my code more readable.